# Optimizing merging multiple dataframes with partial overlapping columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

In my case, I imported nine csvs as dataframes. I need to merge them all into a single dataframe, but there are no universal join keys between them. However, I have identified seven columns that make it possible for all to be joined together.

For example, this is the chart of overlapping columns between my dataframes: [Overlapping columns between dataframes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvysd.png)

I also want to know if it's possible to print out the columns used in the join for each dataframe.

My initial thinking was something along the lines of:

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
# etc.

dfs = [df1, df2, df3] # all dfs go here

shared_columns = ["list of all shared colmns"]

for dataframe in dfs:
    for column in shared_columns:
        try:
            reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=column), dfs)
            dfs.remove(dataframe)
            break
        except:
            pass
```